# Filter table from <select> input using jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, html-table

I'm trying to filter a table from an alphabetical `<select>` input with jQuery.

I have first and last names in two columns of the table, and I'd like to filter the rows by either of these.

I have a select input set up as so:

```
<select>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    ...
</select>
```

and I'd like to filter this table:

```
<tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Schmoe</td>
    <td>$2482.79</td>
    <td>172.78.200.124</td>
    <td>http://gmail.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>$2776.09</td>
    <td>119.232.182.142</td>
    <td>http://www.example.com</td>
</tr>
```

How would I go about filtering the table using jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work assuming you only have one select and one table that is stuctured like your example

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var rows = $('table tr').each(function() {
        var row = $(this);
        var columns = row.children('td');

        row.data('name-chars', [
            columns.eq(0).html()[0].toUpperCase(),
            columns.eq(1).html()[0].toUpperCase(),
        ]);
    });

    $('select').change(function() {
        var char = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

        rows.each(function() {
            var row = $(this);
            var chars_to_match = row.data('name-chars');
            if($.inArray(char, chars_to_match) > -1) {
                row.show();
            }
            else {
                row.hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Now how could I include an `<option>` to show all rows?

Comment: Add first option as 'All' and in the change function if the value is 'All', do $('table tr').show() and you are done.

Comment: Why are you storing the first two characters using 'data' method for each row? If you are going to iterate through all the rows, you might as well get this first two characters on demand.

Comment: awesome function, used this for my scripts!

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this.  Pretty similar to what Elzo came up with but it limits it to the first two columns of the table.

```
 $('select').change( function(e) { 
   var letter = $(this).val();
     if (letter === 'ALL') {
         $ ('tr').show ();
     }
     else {
         $('tr').each( function(rowIdx,tr) {
             $(this).hide().find('td').each( function(idx, td) {
                 if( idx === 0 || idx === 1) {
                     var check = $(this).text();
                     if (check && check.indexOf(letter) == 0) {
                         $(tr).show();
                     }
                 }
             });             

         });
     }             
 });
```

It doesn't ignore case and assumes you have one select and the only tr's on the page are the ones you want to filter.

**EDIT** Added an 'ALL' option to show rows again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If necessary substitute y with $(y).

```
$('tr').hide();
$('select').change( function(){
    var letter = $(this).val();
    var dataset = $('#tableID').find('td');
    $.each(dataset, function(x, y){
        if( y.substr(0,1) == letter){
            y.parent().show();
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit**

@SolutionYogi. You are right. I guess this line can be rewriten as:

```
var dataset = $('#tableID').find('tr').children('td').slice(0,1);
```

Never tried that though.

**EDIT 2**

I tested this. I hope is elegant enough as well and I doesn't have more errors.

```
$('tr').hide();
$('select').change( function(){
    var letter = $(this).val();
    var dataset = $('#tableID').find('tr');
        $.each(dataset, function(x, y){
            var data = $(y).children().slice(0,2);
                $.each(data, function(a, b){
                    if( $(b).html().substr(0,2) == letter){
                        $(b).parent().show();
                    }
             });
       });
});
```

Comment: Your code searches all the columns whereas the author wants to search only first two columns.

Comment: Won't that code only search the first two cells of the first row?

Comment: You are right again. I'll try to find another solution so you wont parse the whole td set.

Comment: Author wants to search first two letters where as you match only one character.

Comment: I modified to substr(0,2). This code is more like a concept to solve a problem then writing code for people. People must be able to change, understand and adapt the code that we are presenting here, otherwise the outcome is futile. True?

Answer (score 0):

If the id of your table is *sel*, and the table is *tab*, this will do the trick. Change *eq(0)* to change the column to look in. An empty value in the select box will re-show all trs.

```
var selSelection = $("#sel").val();
if(!selSelection) $("#tab tr").show();
else $("#tab tr").show().filter(function(index){
    return $("td:eq(0)", this).html().indexOf(selSelection) == -1;
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

$("td:not(:contains('" + input_value + "'))").remove();

This is case sensitive ... what specifically are you attempting to filter on?