# jQuery: Showing a div if a specific a <select> option is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

I'm working on the address page for a shopping cart. There are 2 `<select>` boxes, one for Country, one for Region.

There are 6 standard countries available, or else the user has to select "Other Country". The `<option>` elements all have a numeric value - Other Country is 241. What I need to do is hide the Region `<select>` if the user selects Other Country, and also display a textarea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind a function to the select list so that when it changes, your function decides if the div should be shown. Something like this (<s>untested, hopefully syntactically close</s>). **Here's a [live example](http://jsbin.com/uhozu)**.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#YourSelectList').bind('change', function (e) { 
    if( $('#YourSelectList').val() == 241) {
      $('#OtherDiv').show();
    }
    else{
      $('#OtherDiv').hide();
    }         
  });
});
```

Comment: Legend! This gave me the basic outline, and I was able to figure it out from there. Thanks for your time, and the example you wrote - really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the same principle as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100066/filter-table-from-select-input-using-jquery).  You just need to connect to the change on the select , check the `val()` and `hide()/show()` the div.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you don't really need jQuery for this.

This simple JavaScript code will do the trick:

```
document.getElementById('country_id').onchange = function()
{
    if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 241) {
        document.getElementById('region_id').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('region_id').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

`value` works for most browsers, but yes, for older browsers you need `select.options[select.selectedIndex].value`. I updated my script.

Comment: Haven't tested this, as I ended up using the other solution, but appreciate your input - thank you!

Comment: That's nearly there--you need to index into the select to get the selected option's value. I agree that if you weren't using jquery, this problem wouldn't be a good reason to start. BUT if you already have jquery on the project, go ahead and use it!