# How to filter html table?

Tags: html, filter

Hi I am trying to incorporate Table filtering , where the user can select a author or name and filter the table based on then name . The feed has to be Based on xml feed .

Is there any example that I can use?

I was was looking at this example  http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2/examples/grid/xml-grid.html

or something http://www.picnet.com.au/resources/tablefilter/demo.htm

How can I add a combo box(dropdown box) outside the table to filter based on various authors selection name the feed i would like to use is xml

Or any other example similar to this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be best off using a JavaScript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com), which enables you to use the myriad plugins that are available.

[jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=802) does all of that kind of stuff for you.

Have a look at the [examples here](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) under *Live Data Manipulation > Searching Data*.  You should be able to just replace the `input` with a `select`.

Alternatively, still with jQuery but this question might do what you need: [Filter table from <select> input using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100066/filter-table-from-select-input-using-jquery)

Comment: I like your jqGrid, but it using Php and Mysql. I want it to be purely client side and the feed has to be xml and then manipulated by jquery and on that I just want to add drop down menu outside the table where the user can query directly based on the user name from teh drop down.. I would really appreciate if there is some live working examples..

Comment: @user244394: jqGrid is a plugin for jQuery, which is purely client-side.  Where the data comes from is up to you - here's a tutorial on [reading XML with jQuery](http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question. Filters are generated by jQuery plugin. [Here's step by step manual.](http://www.picnet.com.au/picnet_table_filter.html)

Comment: Yes, It somewhat close to what i was looking for but i want it to be xml feed based and there is no table sort capability on the columns.. I would really appreciate a working exmple..

Answer (score 0):

**Use standard DOM** (DomDocument class). Example: [this testkit loads any HTML DTD](https://github.com/ppKrauss/html5-to-html4/tree/master/testkit), and you can do any filter with a good and standard XSLT transform.