# Filtering information from hidden table to show only the result using Jquery in WP

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, filter

I am trying to filter an answer using 3 x  which selected show a result.

Example 00.5em + 0.1 W + U-BAND := Shakar makar(Result)

After selecting all 3 I should get a result.

Result is taken from a table which is filled with information. But maybe I should choose something else ?

```
<table width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Gate length</th>
            <th>Output Power</th>
            <th>BAND</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <select id="select1">
                    <?php
                    global $wpdb;
                    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT pav FROM test");
                    foreach ($results as $res) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $res->pav; ?>">
                            <?php echo $res->pav; ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </th>
            <th>
                <select id="select2">
                    <?php
                    global $wpdb;
                    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT pav2 FROM test");
                    foreach ($results as $res) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $res->pav2; ?>">
                            <?php echo $res->pav2; ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </th>
            <th>
                <select id="select3">
                    <?php
                    global $wpdb;
                    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT pav3 FROM test");
                    foreach ($results as $res) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $res->pav3; ?>">
                            <?php echo $res->pav3; ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Search result</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="result">
            <td data-green-1="" colspan="3">
                FPA5501150D-P20
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Found some info from here ([Filter table from <select> input using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100066/filter-table-from-select-input-using-jquery)), but its not the right thing. Because all table should be hidden and only after selecting all options the result shown.

So main questions how to create a filtered table? O should I use different approach to this ?

Added. So After a while, I got to this point ->

in general.js i've updated :

```
$("select").click(function(){
    var name1 = $('#select1').val();
    var name2 = $('#select2').val();
    var name3 = $('#select3').val();
    console.log(name1)

    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            action:'table_block',
            realname1: name1,
            realname2: name2,
            realname3: name3,
        },
        success: function (data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    })
})
```

and in function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_table_block', 'table_list');
add_action('wp_ajax_table_block', 'table_list');
function table_list()
{

    if (isset($_POST['realname1'], $_POST['realname2'], $_POST['realname3'])) {
        $name1 = $_POST['realname1'];
        $name2 = $_POST['realname2'];
        $name3 = $_POST['realname3'];
        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT pav4, pav5 FROM test WHERE pav = '$name1' and pav2 = '$name2' and pav3 = '$name3'");
        foreach ($results as $res) {
     

   echo $res['pav4'], $res['pav5'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

}

The problem is I get an error

GET...wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=table_block&realname1=0.1%20um&realname2=0.1%20W&realname3=U-BAND 404 (Not Found). WHy it's not found ?

Comment: where is `Shakar makar` ? Also , there are mutliple tables ?

Comment: No, there is one big table.

Comment: So, can someone help me with this ?

Comment: can you show your attempt i.e : jquery/js code ?

Comment: Updated my try in wp

Comment: Hi, are you sure this `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` url is right ? Also , copy that url and paste in your browser see if that showing you correct page or not .